# Crashes in Android native code are uploaded but not reported on website

Tags: android, crashlytics, google-fabric, crashlytics-android

I updated to the latest Crashlytics libs and it seems the crashes are not reported on the website.
Bellow is my logcat when starting the app, I cause a native crash then restart the application. Log shows like the report was uploaded but I can't see it anywhere.

```
libcrashlytics: Initializing libcrashlytics version 2.0.0
libcrashlytics: Initializing native crash handling successful.
CrashlyticsCore: Initializing Crashlytics 2.5.0.20
CrashlyticsCore: No minidump data found in directory /data/user/0/.../files/.Fabric/com.crashlytics.sdk.android.crashlytics-ndk/native/1515762319997

-----> I cause native crash here

libcrashlytics: Initializing libcrashlytics version 2.0.0
libcrashlytics: Initializing native crash handling successful.
CrashlyticsCore: Initializing Crashlytics 2.5.0.20
cr_CrashFileManager: /data/user/0/.../cache/WebView/Crash Reports does not exist or is not a directory
CrashlyticsCore: Crashlytics report upload complete: 5A58B63A034F-0001-0EA0-1EF6E7C2180A
```

Initially I tried a older version and had some success with it but after upgrading to the latest then going back to the older version that stopped working too. The old version no longer shows a "upload complete" message.

Can you please help, I trying to get this working for 2 days...

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Thanks. Can you let me know what versions of our SDK and build tools you are using in your app? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and after searching for a few hours, I solved it by updating my "google-services.json" file that was not the latest version

Comment: Any answer that gets the asker going in the right direction is helpful, but do try to mention any limitations, assumptions or simplifications in your answer. Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better.